# Laravel 5.4 JQuery Request 405

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, request

I've a Problem with my JQuery post requset in Laravel 5.4. The Opera developer console says, the method is not allowed (403)

My Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('/create', 'ProjectController');
```

The JQuery Request

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#create').on('submit', function () {
        $.post(
            $(this).prop('action'),
            {
                "_token": $(this).find('input[name=_token]').val(),
                "name": $('#name').val(),
                "creator": $('#creator').val(),
                "type": $('#type').val(),
                "game": $('#game').val(),
                "description": $('#description').val(),
            },
            function (data) {
                //TODO: do something with data/response returned by server
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Please help me

//Edit:

The Controller

```
public function store(CreateProjectFormRequest $request)
    {
        $project = new Project;

        $project->name = $request->get('name');
        $project->section = $request->get('section');
        $project->creator = Auth::user()->name;
        $project->game = $request->get('game');
        $project->description = $request->get('description');

        $project->save();
        return 'success';
    }
```

Comment: This is already a post request

Comment: What is the url in `$(this).prop('action')` ?

Comment: `{!! Form::open(['data-toggle' => 'validator', 'url' => '/create', 'class' => 'create']) !!}`

Comment: this means you need to write your storing code inside `store` function of your `ProjectController`

Comment: I#ve added the store function

Comment: You need to add the method to the Form element like {!! Form::open(['data-toggle' => 'validator', 'url' => '/create', 'class' => 'create', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

Comment: have you echo `$project->name`. `die` to see the data is coming or not.

Comment: `$project->name` dose not come and i#ve added the mehod already to the form

Comment: Also please replace you function title with `public function store(Request $request)`. and check

Comment: Nope there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

Change your route : `Route::resource('/create', 'ProjectController');`

To this: : `Route::post('/', 'ProjectController@store');`

> EDIT:

I think you get the error because you submit the form twice. with the form's action adn jQuery.

> 1 solution

Remove all jQuery and add this inside your form: (just a submit button)

```
    {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
```

> 2 solution

remove action from your form and change your jquery request to start like this

```
$.post('/create',
    {
        '_token':......
```

Comment: Method not allowed

Comment: okay, so why not submit with the proper way in laravel and you use jQuery? I cant see the need.